# Where to find "InOut\\" path in csharp?

Tags: c#, inout, jetbrains-rider

I have a charp file and have created in JetBrainsRider -> Console Project.
In main method, there is code as below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FileNamePrefix = string.Empty;
            string InfoFileName = string.Empty;

            if (args.Count() > 0)
            {
                FileNamePrefix = args[0];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Enter File Name (no extension): ");
                FileNamePrefix = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            InfoFileName = "InOut\\" + FileNamePrefix + "-INFO.TXT";
            if (!File.Exists(InfoFileName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist.  Run Terminated", InfoFileName);
                return;
            }
}
```

When I place a TestInput-INFO.TXT file in project folder and give name in readline input, it gives error:

```
Enter File Name (no extension): TestInput
InOut\TestInput-INFO.TXT does not exist.  Run Terminated
```

Where should I put my input file?
[image: Code]

[image: File Location]

Answer (score 1):

It is relative to the current directory — [see `Environment.CurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=net-6.0).

When executing a program from within the IDE, the `exe` file is located in the `bin` folder, and hence that is the current directory for the process.